# I want to submit my custom select field with multiple options selected in checkout form, but it returns only first index?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart-module, opencart2.3

Here is my html

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="billing_address[multi_select_colours_custom][]" id="input-payment-multi-select-colours" class="form-control" required="">
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="white">White</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="brown">Brwon</option>
<option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
```

and here is the opencart ajax data object

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-payment-address input[type=\'text\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'date\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'datetime-local\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'time\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'password\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'hidden\'], #collapse-payment-address textarea, #collapse-payment-address select'),
```

...

Comment: Opencart have an option to add custom fields in address,affiliate and account place

Comment: you can find this on your admin panel: customer > custom fields